# Coldfusion check if input value blank then set in another input

Tags: coldfusion

So I've read a lot of answers but none work for me. I need to **check and see if the input value is empty (blank)**, if it is, **then put the value of another input to empty as well**.

Here is the code:

```
<input name="Main" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" />
<input name="Second" type="hidden" value="" />
```

So when the value of Main is empty, I want to set the value of Second the empty as well.
Here is what I tried:

```
<cfif len(trim(Main)) EQ 0>
    <cfset Second= "">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine other than not specifying the form scope as llya mentions. How did the code not work for you? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Are you setting it on form submission or do you want to clear it on the form itself if the `Main` box is cleared? NOTE: If clearing on the form, you'd probably also want to clear it on submission, too.

Comment: I take it that the hidden field get set via some other processes and the we are trying to override whatever value it may have had on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With scope `form`

```
<cfif len(trim(form.Main)) EQ 0>
     <cfset Second = form.Second>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You probably meant to set the value to an empty string, not `form.Second`? Also, don't forget to scope `Second` as well.

Comment: @IkePr And if the only difference here is that `form` scope is specified, then that suggests to me that, since `form` is one of the last scopes evaluated for an unscoped variable, you may have another variable in a different scope that's named the same as your form name. This can make for a lot of troubleshooting headaches.